# Clickable ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception

I'm looking now a few days for a solution for clickable items in a listView.

First I came across this:
**developer.android.com/resources/articles/touch-mode.html**
and found that it's doesn't have the "normal" onListItemClick() behavouir.

Then I came across of **this code**:
http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/125/

```
// LINE 296-321

    @Override  
    protected ViewHolder createHolder(View v) {  
        // createHolder will be called only as long, as the ListView is not filled  
        // entirely. That is, where we gain our performance:  
        // We use the relatively costly findViewById() methods and  
        // bind the view's reference to the holder objects.  
        TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listitem_text);  
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.listitem_icon);  
        ViewHolder mvh = new MyViewHolder(text, icon);  

        // Additionally, we make some icons clickable  
        // Mind, that item becomes clickable, when adding a click listener (see API)  
        // so, it is not necessary to use the android:clickable attribute in XML  
        icon.setOnClickListener(new ClickableListAdapter.OnClickListener(mvh) {  

            public void onClick(View v, ViewHolder viewHolder) {  
                // we toggle the enabled state and also switch the icon  
                MyViewHolder mvh = (MyViewHolder) viewHolder;  
                MyData mo = (MyData) mvh.data;  
                mo.enable = !mo.enable; // toggle  
                ImageView icon = (ImageView) v;  
                icon.setImageBitmap(  
                        mo.enable ? ClickableListItemActivity.this.mIconEnabled  
                                : ClickableListItemActivity.this.mIconDisabled);  
            }  
        });
```

While debugging I noticed the parameter **View v** is a **TextView** and not a "normal" View and then of course:

```
TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listitem_text);
```

returnes **null** and I get a NullPointerException...

Any ideas why? And how I can solve this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you create your instance of `ClickableListAdapter` ?

When you create your list adapter, you have to pass a resource id `viewId`, this should be a `layout` which will be inflated later.

```
public ClickableListAdapter(Context context, int viewid, List objects) {  

        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.  
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);  
        mDataObjects = objects;  
        mViewId = viewid;
```

Below, the code inflate the xml layout passed to the constructor and call `createHolder`.

```
view = mInflater.inflate(mViewId, null);  
// call the user's implementation  
holder = createHolder(view);
```

So make sure that when instantiating your `ClickableListAdapter`, you pass a `layout` instead of an `id`

**Edit**
You have to create a xml layout with the following which is taken from the link you have provided:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout  
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  android:orientation="horizontal"  
  android:gravity="center_vertical"  
  >  

<TextView android:text="Text" android:id="@+id/listitem_text"  
            android:layout_weight="1"   
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            ></TextView>  
<ImageView android:id="@+id/listitem_icon"  
            android:src="@drawable/globe2_32x32"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:maxWidth="32px"  
            android:maxHeight="32px"  
            >  
</ImageView>  
</LinearLayout>
```

If you call it `mylistrow.xml` in the layout directory, so you construct your adapter as :

```
adapter = new MyClickableChannelListAdapter(this, R.layout.mylistrow, channelList); 
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: **Actually I think I am doing it with:**

    adapter = new MyClickableChannelListAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, channelList);
  setListAdapter(adapter);



**isn't it?**

Comment: Or do I have to do something else to get my own (XML) layout?

Comment: Oh my god... I found the issue... so trivial...

Creating the adapter here it was the wrong list:
dapter = new MyClickableChannelListAdapter(this, R.layout.mylistrow, channelList); 
setListAdapter(adapter);

I mean I used the wrong xml.

Thank you for your help... I was searching hours for such a smal thing...

Comment: Ok I have one more thing which is related to this...
When I select lets say Item 1 and I scroll down and up again Item 2 is selected...
I'm investigating it but if anyone knows this issue I'm thankful for any suggestion :)

Comment: I havent really looked in details to the implementation but check the different values of `position` passed to `getItemId` (just an idea, otherwise, you should post a new question|) - Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

List items should be clickable right out of the box. You can check how lists are coded by looking at `ApiDemos` project code. It should be present on your local machine since it is a part of the SDK. I have it at `<root_sdk_folder>\platforms\android-2.0.1\samples\ApiDemos`.

Comment: As I was writting before...
Here: http://www.developer.android.com/resources/articles/touch-mode.html
ListViews are not clickable by them selves in Touch mode...

I still don't have a solution...

Log.d("TEST...","v.getClass(): "+v.getClass().toString());
shows me: TextView

Log.d("TEST...","v.getParent().getClass(): "+v.getClass().toString());
Shows Nothing... I'm stuck on this :(

Comment: @Beasly: You can also check how list are coded here - http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html

Comment: I'm sorry did you read what I just was writing?
I have seen this before... I was looking for a solution before posting here... and of course I was going through the API

Comment: @Beasly: Sorry for any confusion. I'd just like to say I had not do anything extra to make list items clickable in my projects. This is odd you have such an issue, so I suspect smth is coded in a wrong way. Sorry again if this is not the case for you.

Comment: No problem... I'm open to any suggestion to get it working...
The code I resued is on the link

Comment: Sorry for being a dumb, I've just realized your needs - you want some sub-view within a list item to have some other click listener than the whole list item has by default...