# how to bind an item selected in list view to the other list?

Tags: android, listview

I have created two simple list views. In the first list view I have put category as the item name. And it is the only item which i have included in list one. In the list view I jave put lot of items , say for example orange, Apple, Mango , Banana etc.what i want to know is that if the user selects one particular item in the second list view , I want the selected item to be shown in the first list view.So that it is easy to identify the item which was earlier selected by the user. please help me....

This is my 1st list view code:

```
public class bview extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cat));
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }

    static final String[] cat = new String[] {
        "Category", };
protected void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,
                                                                        long id) {          

            Intent intent= new Intent(bview.this,listview.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            //intent.putExtra("value", value);                    

        }}
```

2nd listview code:

```
    public class listview extends Activity
{    


    @Override    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.submain);


        ListView mlistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        mlistView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                new String[] {"orange", "apple","mango","banana","grapes"}));

 mlistView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3){
         Intent in2 =new Intent(listview.this, bview.class);
         startActivity(in2);
     }
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>arg0){
 }});

}}
```

I used onitemselected but if click orange nothing will be happend. where i should go to wrong in my code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second listview, use a [setOnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29). When the user clicks on one of the items, add it to the datastructure backing your first ListView. So you'd do something like this in your onCreate in you second activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
  //setup your listview here
  myListview.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdpaterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
      //add particular item that was clicked to the backing datastructure 
      // of your listview in the first activity here
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){
      //don't do anything here
    }
  });
  //any other stuff in your onCreate
}
```

Comment: where should i go to implement this source code to my source code...i am new for android application...please tell me...i post my source code...please check and help me....

Comment: Like I said in my answer, this code should be put in the onCreate method in your second activity.

Comment: now i changed my code but, nothing will be happend..please check and let me know....

Comment: Ummm, I didn't provide a complete example. You have to fill in the details your self where I've put comments.

Answer (score 0):

In OnItemClick of second ListView, you can set selected item of first ListView, see [Android - setSelected in OnItemClick in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800415/android-setselected-in-onitemclick-in-listview)