# Removing Item from list view

Tags: java, android, listview, listview-selector

I have a list view with items, that when selected and when a button is pressed, should be deleted. Not sure if the items are being selected at all because nothing is happening.

```
currentDraft = new Draft();
inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
playerListView = (ListView)this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView().findViewById(R.id.player_list); 
playerListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.player_item,R.id.player_name_txt, new ArrayList<String>(){});

playerListView.setAdapter(playerListAdapter);
playerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) {
            view.setSelected(true);
            playerListView.setSelection(position);
            Log.i("DraftBuddy", "Selected: " + position);
        }
    });
```

The Code for the button

```
public void removePlayer(View v)
{
        if(playerListView.getSelectedItem() != null)
        {
            int removeTarget = playerListView.getSelectedItemPosition();
            playerListAdapter.remove(playerListAdapter.getItem(removeTarget));
            playerListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
}
```

The code for the view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mtgdraftbuddy.bryantyoung.draftbuddy2.DraftStart"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contextClickable="true"
    android:background="#0a0909">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/player_list"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/add_player_btn"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Startbtn"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Startbtn"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contextClickable="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Player"
        android:id="@+id/add_player_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="addPlayer" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Draft"
        android:id="@+id/Startbtn"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/add_player_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:id="@+id/removeBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="removePlayer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the log statement is not being printed out to logcat which means it is not being recognized when the user clicks on the list view it is different from the other solutions people have linked. I also tried the solutions before posting the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - setSelected in OnItemClick in ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800415/android-setselected-in-onitemclick-in-listview)

Comment: no it is not because my log statement will not show up which means the click is not being recognized

Comment: Did you define any item in `R.layout.player_item` as clickable?

Comment: remove android:clickable="true" in your relativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing the same thing by instead removing the element in the array.

```
        int removeTarget = playerListView.getSelectedItemPosition();
        playerListView.remove(removeTarget);
        playerListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.getItemAtPosition(position)
```

This return the Object in the `List` which is provided to the `Adapter`,

`Adapter` class has a method to `remove()` a `element` from the provided `list`

```
adapter.remove("here provide the object which you want to remove")
```

something like this

```
 private int TRACK = 0; // make a variable where you can track which item was clicked in the listview
```

in your `listview` you have to keep track of which item was clicked, `TRACK`

```
playerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) {
            TRACK = position;
            Log.i("DraftBuddy", "Selected: " + position);
        }
    });
```

this is code which you can use to call from the button click

```
public void removePlayer(View v)
{
        if(playerListView.getSelectedItem() != null)
        {

             playerListAdapter.remove(playerListView.getItemAtPosition(TRACK));
             playerListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
}
```

> Update

if I believe right that you want to remove the an item from the Listview which one is clicked.

if this case you can get the item which is been clicked like this,

```
playerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) {
              playerListAdapter.remove(playerListView.getItemAtPosition(position));
              playerListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```